# Running Jmeter commands through own batch file gives error Error: Unable to access jarfile ApacheJMeter.jar errorlevel=1

Tags: batch-file, jmeter

I am not able to run jmeter commands through my own batch file.
Can some one guide me what is the problem.
I am getting the error

```
 Error: Unable to access jarfile ApacheJMeter.jar errorlevel=1
```

Have added this simple command in test.bat file

```
start D:\JMeter\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\jmeter -n -t D:\JMeter\JMeterTestFiles\LoadTest.jmx -l D:\JMeter\JMeterTestFiles\summary.jtl
```

Comment: 1. Try to `cd` to the directory where `ApacheJMeter.jar` is located (in case it even exists); 2. put all paths in between `""`; 3. add `""` (empty window title) between `start` and the first parameter (delimited by spaces)...

Comment: Some kind of feedback would be nice. Didn't my answer solve your problem? I'd be quite surprised because I faithfully reproduced your situation.

Comment: Hey hi. Sorry for late reply. It was permission issue for batch file. When I executed it as application admin, its working fine. Anyways thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line before the one you have already:

```
SET JMETER_BIN=D:\JMeter\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\
```

Note that this really shouldn't be necessary... Is your batch file located in a directory which is *not* `D:\JMeter\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\`, but contains a file called `jmeter.bat`, by chance?